# Cannot change TextView when clicked, in ListView

Tags: android, listview

This is my onItemClickListener Method

```
//list item listener
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
         LinearLayout parent = (LinearLayout) view;
         TextView t = (TextView) parent.findViewById(R.id.grocery_item_name);

         t.setText("Something");
}
```

Edit: This is the Adapter Class

code to call adapter:

```
adapter = new CustomList(this,R.layout.listitems_improved,Items);

listview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

---

```
    private class CustomList extends ArrayAdapter{

        ArrayList<Item> items;
        Activity myActivity;
        LayoutInflater layoutinflater;
        View myview;

        public ProductsCustomList(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<item> i) {
            super(context, resource, p);
            this.items = i;
            this.myActivity = (Activity) context;
        }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            //Inflate the custom row layout in the view
            layoutinflater = myActivity.getLayoutInflater();
            myview = layoutinflater.inflate(R.layout.groceryitems_custom_listview, null);

            //instantiate the views in custom row layout
            TextView tv = (TextView) myview.findViewById(R.id.tv);

            tv.setText(items.get(position).getItemName());


            return myview;
        }
}
```

When I call this line `t.setText("Something");` textview doesn't change in the ListView, nothing happens. Why is it not wokring here?

Comment: print what is inside `items.get(position).getItemName()`, may getItemName is empty

Comment: After `t.setText("Something");` use `yourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: @diogojme Text is already set in ListView, I want to change the text once it has been set, there's nothing wrong with `getItemName()` method

Comment: Nothing happens when `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` is called

Comment: Ok, so i think you are doing it by the wrong way, you have to pass the  Something value  to your adapter, then call `notifyDataSetChanged`. And use a ViewHolder in your adapter or it will never work. Please read this sample for you to know how about `Android ViewHolder Pattern`. http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/09/android-viewholder-pattern-example.html

Comment: @diogojme Sir, My ListView is working correctly, all the items are added to listview as it should. but when I click an Item I want to change the text. 
The text is not changing when any of the item is clicked

Comment: You do not need to call notifyDataSetChanged, you should only use it when an item has changed or there's a structural change in items list.
Make sure first the onItemClick method is called, you can use a break point or Log for example.

Comment: Could you please add  your adapter code in your question?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
final Adapter yourAdapter = new Adapter(context, items);

listview.setAdapter(yourAdapter);

listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l){

     //change value for item select
     items.get(i).setItemName("yourText");

     yourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
     //if the this line don't refresh the list, you can recreate adapter:
     //listview.setAdapter(new Adapter(context, items); 

}
```

Regards.

Comment: This does the trick but It will be not feasible when list is Huge, and secondly it also changes the object value, I only want to change the textview while keeping the original values in `items`

Answer (score 1):

Please try this  in your getView() method in your Adapter class:

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            //Inflate the custom row layout in the view
            layoutinflater = myActivity.getLayoutInflater();
            myview = layoutinflater.inflate(R.layout.groceryitems_custom_listview, null);

            //instantiate the views in custom row layout
            TextView tv = (TextView) myview.findViewById(R.id.tv);
            tv.setText(items.get(position).getItemName());


           myview.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                TextView view = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.your_text_id);
                view.setText("text_changed");
            }
        });


            return myview;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You also can try to include the listener in adapter:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        //Inflate the custom row layout in the view
        layoutinflater = myActivity.getLayoutInflater();
        myview = layoutinflater.inflate(R.layout.groceryitems_custom_listview, null);

        //instantiate the views in custom row layout
        TextView tv = (TextView) myview.findViewById(R.id.tv);

        tv.setText(items.get(position).getItemName());


        tv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0){                 
                    tv.setText("selected");                 
                }               
        });


        return myview;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
         LinearLayout parent = (LinearLayout) view;
         TextView t = (TextView) parent.getChilldId(i).findViewById(R.id.grocery_item_name);

         t.setText("Something");
}
```